# In eo.editor.js > storageManager, what does the "type: local " property mean?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

In eo.editor.js > storageManager, what does the "type: local " property mean ?

```js
 storageManager: {
        type: 'local',
       
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching up the remote storage is very simple, it's just a matter of specifying your endpoints for storing and loading, which generally might be also the same (if you rely on HTTP methods).

```js
const editor = grapesjs.init({
  ...
  storageManager: {
    type: 'remote',
    stepsBeforeSave: 3,
    urlStore: 'http://endpoint/store-template/some-id-123',
    urlLoad: 'http://endpoint/load-template/some-id-123',
    // For custom parameters/headers on requests
    params: { _some_token: '....' },
    headers: { Authorization: 'Basic ...' },
  }
});
```

As you can see we've left some default option unchanged, increased changes necessary for autosave triggering and passed remote endpoints.

you can set type to local and remote